# add images to UIBarButtonItem of toolbar in ios

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, iboutlet

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that does not take the picture

I have a toolbar with a button `UIBarButtonItem` above, connected via `IBOutlet`. The image that I put you do not see.

**My code:-**

```
 @interface ViewController : {
   IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;
   IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * myBackButton;
   IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * myReloadButton;
   IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * myHomeButton;
   IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * myListButton;
   IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * myCalendarbutton;//the problem is this

 }
```

the button is connect by `IB` but does not take the picture.

this is the image

[image]

this is the `IB`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` will not allow you to put background image.
Try to use normal `UIButton` and try to use image as a background to the `UIButton`.
Get the action of the `UIButton` and you will get your desired output.